# How do i create a 4 dimensional array from a database

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to make this code work. Basically i have used MySQL to fetch an associative array containing multiple values.

example database: database name = Products

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------.
|   name     | overcategory |   category   |     subcategory     |
|  Talon     |    null      | stud welding | capacitor discharge |
| cdss m3x40 | studs/bolts  |   cd-studs   |   stainless steel   |
----------------------------------------------------------------.
```

I used the sentence `SELECT name, overcategory, category, subcategory FROM Products WHERE 1 = 1;`

In the actual database there are more entries, but they are not relevant for this question.

The result i want to output as a menu on the left hand side of the screen.

```
<nav>
   <h1> "$overcategory" </h1>
     <h2> "$category" </h2>
         <h3> "$subcategory" </h3>
           <a href = "">$productname </a>
           <a href = "">$productname3 </a>

   <h1> "$overcategory2" </h1>
     <h2> "$category2" </h2>
         <h3> "$subcategory2" </h3>
           <a href = "">$productname2 </a>
</nav>
```

i was thinking of doing this by creating a multidimensional array that would look something like this:

```
    $testArray = array(
        ''=>array(
              'Boltsveiseapparater'=>array(
                            'Kondensator'=>array(
                                         'Talon',
                                         'LBS-75'
                                        ),
                                    'Arc'=>array(
                                         'LBH-410',
                                         'LBH-800'
                                        )
                                  )
            ),
            'Pinner/bolter'=>array(
                                        'CD-pinner'=>array(
                                                            'rustfri'=>array(
                                                                            'cdss m3x35',
                                                                            'cdss m3x40'
                                                                            ),
                                                              'stål'=>array(
                                                                            'cdms m3x35',
                                                                            'cdms m6x35'
                                                                            ),
                                                                'Alu'=>array(
                                                                            'cdal m3x10',
                                                                            'cdal m8x80'
                                                                            )
                                                        ),
                                        'Bossinger'=>array(
                                                            'Stål'=>array(
                                                                            'M6x10 5x8',
                                                                            'M5x12 4x10'
                                                                            ),
                                                                'Alu'=>array(
                                                                            'M6x10 5x8',
                                                                            'M5x12 4x10'
                                                                            ),
                                                            'Rustfri'=>array(
                                                                            'M6x10 5x8',
                                                                            'M5x12 4x10'
                                                                            )
                                                        )
                                )

      );
```

I have no idea how to do this by looping through the results. is there any way of doing this without making a giant array of doom? if not, can someone assist me in decyphering this conundrum.

Thank you in advance.
BM.

Comment: I used a combination of the html loop from pferate and the sql query from nnicols and it worked perfectly. I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort each of the columns of your results in your SQL query, you can just loop through each result and compare it with the last entry and adjust your output based on that.

```
SELECT name, overcategory, category, subcategory FROM Products ORDER BY overcategory, category, subcategory, name;
```

Otherwise, here is one way of handling your nested array:

```
<?php

echo "\n";
echo "<nav>\n";
foreach ($testArray as $overcategory_name => $category_data) {
    echo "\t<h1>$overcategory_name</h1>\n";
    foreach ($category_data as $category_name => $subcategory_data) {
        echo "\t\t<h2>$category_name</h2>\n";
        foreach ($subcategory_data as $subcategory_name => $product_name_data) {
            echo "\t\t\t<h3>$subcategory_name</h3>\n";
            foreach ($product_name_data as $product_name) {
                echo "\t\t\t\t<a href = \"\">$product_name</a>\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "</nav>\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me! I can't give you the right answer credit because i used both your solution and nnicols' solution. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could let mysql sort the result set:

```
SELECT name, overcategory, category, subcategory FROM Products ORDER BY overcategory,category,subcategory;
```

Then you can simply loop over the result. Whenever the overcategory, category, subcategory changes you output a new header.

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT name, overcategory, category, subcategory FROM Products WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY overcategory,category,subcategory, name;');

$aMenu = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $aMenu[$row['overcategory']][$row['category']][$row['subcategory']][] = $row['name'];
}
```

A more significant issue to be looking into is your table structure.  Assuming that the overcategory, category and subcategory are part of a hierarchy then you should only be storing the leaf node to which the product belongs, and that should probably be stored as an integer that is a FK to a `categories(id, name, parent_id)` table.  I tend to opt for nested sets for product catalogs but it depends on the requirements.

Furthermore, it is common for an individual product to be represented in more than one category, in which case you would need to move the category relationship to a join table `products_categories(product_id, category_id)`.

Just a little food for thought.

Comment: Looks like this would generate only a single level of menu for every single subcategory.  Also, looks like individual product names would be ignored.  Am I missing something?

Comment: He is generating the nested array that OP described.  That is probably the simplest way to do it and how I would do it as well.  The product name is being added with the last `[]` with the default numbered array keys.  The others are using keys named from the results.

Comment: @ebyrob - thank you for pointing that out. I did miss off the final pair of `[]` but the rest of it works fine. @pferate - cheers!

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me! I can't give you the right answer credit because i used both your solution and pferate's solution. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: In that case give the credit to @pferate. It is better that the question is marked as answered.